# How to configure different loggers separately in structlog?

Tags: python, logging, structlog

structlog.configure() seems to be the global setting. I need to create two different loggers with different settings.Hope someone can give me the right solution, thanks!

```
logger1 = structlog.get_logger()
logger2 = structlog.get_logger()

logger1.configure(
    processors=[do_something1],
)
logger2.configure(
    processors=[do_something2],
)
```

Comment: I am not familiar with structlog, but is it possible that you can simply pass the arguments you are giving to `configure` directly to `get_logger` instead (and not call `configure` at all)? The documentation seems to support this idea, though doesn't explicitly say it.